# JavaScript function is called and looped while bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, toggle, bind

[`Jsfiddle Demo for working version`](http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/84Kd5/15/)

[`Jsfiddle demo for failure version`](http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/84Kd5/16/)

The situation is complicated. I am trying to create an off-canvas navigation sidebar for mobile devise. The idea is like Facebook mobile and Google Plus mobile.

Now the progress is up to here [`Jsfiddle Demo for working version`](http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/84Kd5/15/). (Note it only shows toggle button when the screen is smaller than 768px. It is designed that way.)

For the next step, I want to allow users exit sidebar mode by clicking the dark shadow area. To do that, I `bind` & `unbind` `RightHandSide_wrapper.click` event with sidebar `toggle function`.

[`Jsfiddle demo for failure version`](http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/84Kd5/16/)

JavaScript:

```
var toggle_offcanvas = function(){
    if(
        offcanvas_toggle.prop("checked") == false
    ){
        offcanvas_toggle.prop("checked", true);
         rhs_wrapper.css('cursor', 'pointer' ); 
        rhs_wrapper.css('background-color', 'gray' ); 
        rhs_wrapper.bind("click",toggle_offcanvas);   
        console.log("show slidebar");                
    }
    else 
        {
        offcanvas_toggle.prop('checked', false);
         rhs_wrapper.css('cursor', 'default' ); 
        rhs_wrapper.css('background-color', 'inherit' ); 
        rhs_wrapper.unbind("click",toggle_offcanvas); 
        console.log("hide slidebar");
    }
}
;


$(".offcanvas_button").bind("click",toggle_offcanvas);
```

Here is the problem. After adding `rhs_wrapper.bind("click",toggle_offcanvas);`, every time I click the toggle button it runs the `toggle_offcanvas` function twice. This can be observed from console log, every click on toggle button returns two console outputs: `show slidebar` and `hide slidebar`.

It looks like the function  `toggle_offcanvas` is recalled while I am binding it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/8XSJJ/

The problem is that you're binding the click handler to the div that contains the button, and this triggers the handler twice. So i added a different layer

```
<div class="graybg">
</div>
```

With styling to make it transparent:

```
.graybg {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100; /* behind slide_nav but above everything else */
    display:none; /* initially hidden */
}
```

And basically in the code instead of rhs_wrapper you use this new layer.

Comment: Great answer. And I just learnt that event.stopPropagation() can help stop double trigger. But I also implemented the graybg filter layer that you suggested. It is nice and clean in css.